# Search through data Multidimensional array

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, uisearchbar

i've have this NSMutableArray called finalArray where i add the name and a image.

```
[finalArray addObject:@[name, image]];
```

in the following method its searching through the finalarray, but because its not expecting a multidimensional array it seem to give an error. How can i in this code:

```
    self.filteredArray = [[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

get all the name objects from the finalArray? since that is what this code expect:

```
[[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
```

the method:

```
-(void) searchThroughdata {

    self.filteredArray = nil;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [c] %@",self.searchBar.text];


    self.filteredArray = [[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

            [tableViewData reloadData];



}
```

How do i add the image that belong to the name in the finalarray and still only search through the names like it do now with this?

```
[[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I don't understand. `[finalArray addObject:name];` is not searching through an array. It is just adding an object to the end of a mutable array. What is the structure of your multidimensional array? Please can you explain at a higher level what you are trying to do.

Comment: check again please :)

Comment: OK, makes sense now :) my answer is still valid. Use a custom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to associate names and images with each other by using the same index of an array or something? Am I right?

If so then you should really be using a custom class to do this...

```
@interface MyNameImageClass : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property UIImage *image;

@end
```

Now you can create the object...

```
MyNameImageClass *object = [MyNameImageClass new];
object.name = theName;
object.image = theImage;
```

Then just add this to an array...

```
[finalArray addObject:object];
```

Having said that though, you need to clarify what you are asking. The question is very confusing.

By doing this if the image is updated on the object you don't need to reinsert it into the array. The array stores a reference to the object so the array will have the updated value too.

Comment: From this how do i then get all the object.name values from the finalArray?

Comment: @user3258468 you would do `MyNameImageClass *myImg = finalArray[someIndex];` then `myImg.name` will access that name.